# Nullpointer exception on activity launch

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bin, dex

I have an error in the perfectly running app before. The snapshot shown here came after i cleaned the project. The android code is perfectly right to my best knowledge.

```
   package com.tmresponseportal;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Client1 extends Activity {
TextView text1,tvforpass;
EditText tbid,tbpwd;
Button bsubmit,bclose;
Emailval el = new Emailval();


public void Intentstr() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i1 = new Intent();
    i1.setClass(Client1.this,Clwelcome2.class);
    startActivity(i1);

}

public void Intent_start2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i2 = new Intent();
    i2.setClass(Client1.this,Forpass.class);
    startActivity(i2);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client1);


    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text1.setSelected(true);
    tbid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbid);
    tbpwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbpwd);
    bsubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsubmit);
    bclose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bclose);
    tvforpass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvforpass);


    tvforpass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {





    bclose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             finish();
                System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_client1, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

The app force closes when I try to run or debug it. It wont even launch!! The logcat shows nullpointer exception.

I think the error is something to do with bin>dexedlib or the build path.

[image: here is logcat img]

Does anyone have any idea about it.
any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.!

[here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVdxj.png)

Comment: Check the problems tab to see what the error is.

Comment: Could you post your logcat?

Comment: go to ->show view ->problms ans check what problem is there...

Comment: the error tab SHOWED that file 39ce...something in bin is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project have some library errors,

Go to properties then fix your java build path, and check if you are using any library project, it should be at same location as your main project

Comment: project build optin is not allowed!! :(

Answer (score 0):

Check for missing libs . Fix project properties and clean it again.

Comment: Try to check Window-->Show view -- > Problems  tab.

Comment: add libs folder in your project and add all external library in it, check if you have multiple copy of same library....mostly  this dex related error with library location.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I myself am answering my silly question !!
The library annotations-3e4e92ba3f3a5427576379deacae2306-e9d0b35cdf8dc6a314b668efa54277b9.jar 
was somehow deleted.

I restored it back and it worked.

To retrieve,
Right click on the project> Restore local History> And the library I wanted.

Done  :)